# Iframe src keeps on changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Hi i have an iframe in my website. The problem is the src of that site keeps changing when a person logs out from that website.

From this:
https://172.16.8.187:6060/cewolf;jsessionid=AB817C6CBF0945CBE62B91C714C0D570?img=605210234&width=900&height=250&iehack=.png
to 
https://172.16.8.187:6060/cewolf;jsessionid=B6693C4BF4247CB18537274062DB3A65?img=-1673722298&width=900&height=250&iehack=.png

I mean the src would change randomly which is a problem with my iframe because the src keeps on changing in the website. Is there any script that will make my iframe src adapt automatically whenever the src changes? I need this badly for my internship. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please fix your images, we are unable to see them

Comment: You dont need the images. That's just the src of my iframe and how it changes. It changes whenever a person logs out from that remote website.

Comment: This isn't a free coding service you must show what you have tried.Generous people might still post a solution but your problem is very confusing post a well described scenario then you might get a few answers